# JNI signature code analysis

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, code-analysis

Is there any static code analysis tool which discovers errors in JNI (method) signature strings? For example, that the following code is not syntactically correct (missing semicolon after full qualified class name):

```
(*env)->GetMethodID(env, someClassId, "aMethod","(ILfoo/bar/TheClass)V");
```

**edit:** The code analysis tool does not need to check the existence of foo/bar/TheClass, but only check the string for valid syntax according to the JNI spec.

The background of this question is, that the above code triggered a segmentation fault. This is always an annoying debugging situation, but static analysis should be pretty easy in this case saving a lot of time.

Comment: +1, good question! But doesn't the JNI API have methods to retrieve a class name signature as a string? (edit: there is: `javap`)

Comment: @fge right, thanks. But that doesn't help for existing projects and it's not handy when creating new code. This ends up using copy/paste and does not prove code correctness.

Comment: The above code shouldn't trigger a segmentation fault. Lack of error checking afterwards will cause that. That's where you should be directing your attention, that and unit testing, always essential with JNI.

Comment: @EJP I don't think it is helpful to do dynamic verification to check for problems which are completely static. In general I agree, testing is ONE way to archive code quality, but it's not the focus of my question.

Comment: It's helpful if that's your only choice, which it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need static analysis of cases like the one in your question, where the signature is directly inside the `GetMethodID` call, you could just write a quick script that walks over the code files and finds all `GetMethodID`/`GetFieldID` invocations with a regex and then verifies the syntax.

But what you can always use is the `-Xcheck:jni` ([Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbmtq)/[IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50%2Fdiag%2Funderstanding%2Fjni_debug.html)) option to debug these issues. JNI calls will be slower because of the validation that is done by the JVM but the required debugging effort is significantly reduced.

Comment: I don't want to write it myself this time ;-) I've already seen the -Xcheck:jni argument, which is in deed very useful, but I would really prefer a static analysis method. Thanks anyway.